# How do I handle excess characters read from cin?

Tags: c++

In the code below when I run it and if I entered more than 30 character while the runtime It will not read `linesNum1` nor `text[]` at all.

So I think it stores the extra character from `array1[30]` and uses it in `linesNum1`.

So how can I clear the cache of the program, or make it `cin` the `linesNum1` and `text[]` even if I entered more characters than `array1` can hold?

```
char array1[30];
for (int i = 0; i<30; i++)
    cin >> array1[i];
int linesNum1;
cin >> linesNum1;
int linesNum2 = linesNum1*80;

char text[linesNum2];
for (int i = 0; i < linesNum2; i++)
    cin >> text[i];

for (int i = 0; i < linesNum2; i++)
    cout << text[i];
```

Comment: You asked a perfectly good question, it is unlikely people will downvote you.

Comment: The answer to this question has some advice about avoiding input buffer overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4895216/testing-buffer-overrun-of-input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to flush the `stdin` buffer in order to get rid of the possible extra characters.

You can use [`istream::ignore`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) to discard all available characters in the stream :

```
//Will discard everything until it reaches EOF.
cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max());

//Will discard everything until it reaches a new line.
cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Example :

```
/* read 30 chars */
for (int i = 0; i<30; i++) cin >> array1[i];
/* discard all extra chars on the line */
cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
/* clear the stream state flags */
cin.clear();
cin >> linesNum1;
...
```

Comment: i'm using
`using namespace std;` in the header of my program , can you explain this answer more please ??

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking for is `std::cin.ignore(INT_MAX);`.

This will read in and ignore everything until EOF. Also, You will most likely want to do an `std::cin.clear();` before this too to reset the stream.

**EDIT:**
Along with cin.ignore() is the optional second parameter to add in:

```
std::cin.ignore(INT_MAX,'\n');
```

Which will ignore till the end of line.